# QtSerialPort communication issue

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu-13.10, qtserialport

```
QSerialPort *serial;
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    serial = new QSerialPort(this);
    serial->setPortName("/dev/ttyUSB0");
    serial->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
    serial->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    serial->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serial->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serial->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(serialReceived())); 
    connect(ui->pushButton_2, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(serialSent()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    serial->close();
}
void MainWindow::serialReceived()
{
    ui->label->setText(serial->readAll());
}
void MainWindow::serialSent()
{
    QByteArray bytes;
    serial->write(bytes);
}
```

From this code I 've run in qt on Ubuntu. It show QIOdevice::write device not open. But I already plug my usb to serial on this port how can I solve this problem.

Comment: have you tried the qt examples of serial port communications?  There are examples showing how to enumerate devices and come up with the ones that are available.

Comment: You ignore all kind of error checking. You will not proceed without checking those.

Comment: Can you connect to your device with minicom or similar? Are you sure it is connected and available? You can enumerate the available ports with:     QList<QSerialPortInfo> ports = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();
    qDebug() << "Ports enumeration:" << "\n";
    for (int i=0; i < ports.size(); i++) {
        qDebug() << " * Name: " << ports.at(i).portName()
    }

Comment: The connection is available and now it 's work I use the command as chmod 777 ./my port Thank you again

Comment: @user297475: are you in the proper group like "uucp" or so?

Answer (score 0):

1) In ubuntu for access to serial port you must have the right permission. Try to run your code with sudo command.

2) The various settings for serial port must be done after that the port was opened, change your code like this:

```
serial->setPortName("/dev/ttyUSB0");
if(serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite){
   serial->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
   serial->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
   serial->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
   serial->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
   serial->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
}
```

Every settings can return true or false. Correct way is check everyone!